# putch function in assembly language through stack

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, emu8086

I am making a program in assembly language in which i am trying to display a character on the console by pushing the character in to the stack. I am using service number 2 of interrupt 21H to print the character.

When i run the program, the character is displayed on the console but the problem is that it displays infinite times on the console. I am not using any loop so don't know why it's printed infinite times on the console.

Help needed to figure out the problem.

I am using emu8086.

```
.model small
.data
st1 db "A",'$' 
.code
main proc
    mov AX,@data
    mov DS, AX

    mov AX, offset st1
    push AX

    call putch

    putch proc near
        mov BP,SP 
        mov DX,[BP+2]
        mov AH,2
        INT 21H
        ret
    putch endp 

    mov AH,4CH
    INT 21H

end main
```

Comment: Don't put your `putch` procedure in the middle of `main` ...

Comment: it's because `putch` is "in the way". It's after `call putch` but before `AH=4Ch/INT 21`. Move it after that. Also use `ret 02h` or `add sp, 02h` in the caller. Another thing: are you sure about the `mov ax, OFFSET st1`, shouldn't it be `mov al, BYTE PTR [st1]`?

Comment: actually i am trying to push st1 in to the stack and then print the character through stack. if i do this mov al, BYTE PTR [st1], then i will not be able to push it in the stack as AL is 8-bit and 8-bits cannot be pushed in to the stack.

Comment: @MargaretBloom i moved putch after exit statements as you said but now character isn't displayed on the console.

Comment: You can still push *AX*, as AH will not be  used in the procedure it doesn't matter what it contains. I'm leaving the other details to the good person willing to answer.

Comment: Did anyone else initially read the title as [putsch](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/putsch) function?

Comment: The emu8086 has built-in debugger, where you can watch why something happen and what are the actual values in registers, when it happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next image illustrates the problem :

- When you call `putch` the program jumps as the red arrow.
- When `putch` finishes it returns to the call as the green arrow.
- Then the program continues (blue arrow) and executes the next line, which is `putch` again (that's a loop).

[image]

The solution is to move above the block that finishes the program. Another problem is that your program requires a stack. Finally, @MargaretBloom is right (as usual), your code is pushing the address of the string, but you are using `int 21h` `ah=2` to display the char, so there are two options : **#1** push the char and display with `ah=2`, or, **#2** push the address and display with `ah=9` :

**#1**

```
.model small
.stack 100h              ;◄■■ STACK!!!
.data
st1 db "A",'$' 
.code
main proc
    mov AX,@data
    mov DS, AX

    xor ax, ax           ;◄■■ CLEAR AX.
    mov AL, st1          ;◄■■ CHAR IN AX.
    push AX              ;◄■■ PUSH THE CHAR.

    call putch

    mov AH,4CH           ;◄■■ FINISH PROGRAM HERE.
    INT 21H

    putch proc near
        mov BP,SP 
        mov DX,[BP+2]    ;◄■■ THE CHAR.
        mov AH,2         ;◄■■ 2 = DISPLAY ONE CHAR.
        INT 21H
        ret
    putch endp 

end main
```

**#2**

```
.model small
.stack 100h              ;◄■■ STACK!!!
.data
st1 db "A",'$' 
.code
main proc
    mov AX,@data
    mov DS, AX

    mov AX, offset st1   ;◄■■ GET THE ADDRESS.
    push AX              ;◄■■ PUSH THE ADDRESS.

    call putch

    mov AH,4CH         
    INT 21H

    putch proc near
        mov BP,SP 
        mov DX,[BP+2]    ;◄■■ GET THE ADDRESS.
        mov AH,9         ;◄■■ 9 = DISPLAY STRING '$' TERMINATED.
        INT 21H
        ret
    putch endp 

end main
```

Comment: Nice drawing, too bad that it's wrong :) The `RET` goes back to `putch` again, not the `CALL`, and the second time it will try to use the pushed `AX` as the return address.

Comment: @Jester, why does it go back to putch?

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez i think RET goes back to the next line after the CALL, not the CALL itself. In my code, next line to CALL is putch again, so RET takes it back to putch again.

Comment: @Yousaf and everyone, I just moved the green arrow a little lower (happy Jester?).

Comment: I am always happy, but it's still wrong :P The actual cycle is through the `st1` because the second time the `ret` is hit, the return address is no longer on the stack, only the pushed `st1` is, so  it will go there, interpret stuff as code and if you are lucky then fall through into `main` again.

Comment: @Jester, the funny thing is that there was no stack on the original code so the `ret` was jumping back to `putch` over and over.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say. In real mode there is always a stack, since SS:SP always points somewhere. First time around, the `push ax; call` placed `st1` and the return address onto the stack, when `ret` is reached it pops the return address but leaves `st1` on the stack, the second time (no more `call`) only `st1` is on the stack so `ret` pops that and goes there.

Comment: You missed updating the part that says *which is putch again (that's a loop).*  It's not a loop, because when it falls into `putch` instead of CALLing it, RET will go somewhere else.

Comment: For some reason somewhere else is `putch` again, and again, and again...